# Unable to resolve host address Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, error-handling, terminal, cube

Trying to set up Ubuntu to download apps offline on my PC. I'm trying to install cubeget at the moment, but I'm getting errors when trying to install some packages and I'm not sure why.

Here is the error:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/cube-server/4.0/4-0.1/+download/cube4_0.1-0_Linux64.zip

Resolving launchpad.net (launchpad.net)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to solve host address 'launchpad.net'
```

I've tried taking out the https: , as some pages have suggested, but it makes no difference.

Any ideas on how to solve this issues? Thanks

Comment: Are you able to `wget google.com`? If your DNS isn't working, then this command should also fail. You can also add the flags `-d` and `-v` to `wget`  to get verbose and debug output.

Comment: yeah google.com gives the same error

Comment: Try `ping google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8`. If the first command fails, but the second works, then it's a DNS problem. Unfortunately, I don't really know enough about DNS configuration to help much more. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: hmm both commands fail, 'ping google.com' gives a 'Temporary failure in name resolution'. 'ping 8.8.8.8' gives 'Network is unreachable'

Comment: Wait! Did you mean to write "offline" in your question? You can't download things offline, you have to be online.